# Can't access state from parent component method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing a method call to its child components (Keyboard and Key) using props, but when I try to execute the method in the child (Key), the method can't access the original component (Calculator) state, returning undefined

```js
class Calculator extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      display : "nothing now"
      keys : [
        {
          class: "digit",
          label : "0", 
          id : "zero",
          fn : this.setCalculation  
        }
      ]
    }

    this.setCalculation = this.setCalculation.bind(this)
  }


  setCalculation(){
    console.log(this.state.display) // return undefined when I click a Key Component

  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div id="calculator">
          <Display content={this.state.display}/>
          <Keyboard keys={this.state.keys}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Keyboard extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render(){
    let keys = this.props.keys.map((v) => {
      return <Key data={v}/>
    })

    return(
      <div id="keyboard">{keys}</div>
    )
  }
}

class Key extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)    
    this.execute = this.execute.bind(this)
  }  

  execute(e){
    this.props.data.fn(this.props.data.label)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className={"key " + this.props.data.class} style={{gridArea : this.props.data.id}} onClick={this.execute}><span>{this.props.data.label}</span></div>
      )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Calculator />,document.getElementById("app"))
```

Need the method to return the Calculator component state values

Comment: in the example I want to print the state value, not return anything as said. SO is not allowing me to edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comma you forgot after "nothing now", you need to bind the setCalculation method before defining the component state.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.setCalculation = this.setCalculation.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    display : "nothing now",
    keys : [
      {
        class: "digit",
        label : "0", 
        id : "zero",
        fn : this.setCalculation  
      },
    ],
  };
}
```